# Viewing ssrs reports in aspx page

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am trying to show ssrs report in aspx page. when i click on the below link i can see the report..

http://aefyhcpnsvaia09/Reports/Pages/Report.aspxItemPath=%2fIncidentReport%2fIpCenter_assignmet

for the above link what will be the serverReport.ReportServerUrl and serverReport.ReportPath?

for below code I am getting error "The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. (rsInvalidItemPath)"

```
serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://aefyhcpnsvaia09/ReportServer");
serverReport.ReportPath = "Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=IncidentReport%2fIpCenter_assignmet";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the report path to:

```
serverReport.ReportPath = "/IncidentReport/IpCenter_assignmet";
```